# Syntax error when I copied Twilio code to PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, twilio-api

I'm trying out Twilio and I sent the test message in Twilio and it worked (I got the text message on my phone); I copied the Python code it generated and pasted it in PyCharm but when I run it in Powershell it gives me a syntax error. pip install of twilio was succesful and I also installed the twilio package in PyCharm.

I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong since it worked perfectly on Twilio.

This is the code I pasted in PyCharm directly from Twilio (I used the correct account_sid and auth_token):

```
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = 'XYZ'
auth_token = 'abc'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(
  from='+xxx',
  body='a message!',
  to='+xxx'
)

print(message.sid)
```

The syntax error in Powershell:

```
 line 8
    from='+16504698974',
    ^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried assigning 'from', 'body' and 'to' to variables before the message object and using them in the message object but that did not work. I also tried putting them all on the same line; still got the same syntax error.

Comment: `from` is a reserved keyword in Python.  It looks like you need to use the name `from_` for this specific parameter.